# How to hide status bar in service class?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I need to use the following line in service class

> getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(8);

Please anyone help.

Comment: Have the `Service` broadcast an `Intent` and have a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` hide the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

A service can not set window properties, since it has no view/UI. You must send an event to your activity, which must set this property. When it comes to sending the event to activity, you can use several mechanisms:

1. Use a messenger which you passed from activity to service earlier
2. Use AIDL interface
3. Easiest : Send a broadcast `Intent` from your `Service` class, let your `Activity` listen for that broadcast, and set the action on UI thread